# Mouse clicks stopped working in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mouse, dell-latitude

I have a Dell Latitude with windows 7. After a year of usage, the mouse clicks suddenly stopped working. It behaves like this with both the native mice, and with a USB mouse.

Left-clicks stopped working all together. Right-click sometimes work, but most of the time, it does unwanted things.

I suspect it’s some malware, so I ran AVG, SpyBot and MalwareBytes, but found nothing. I checked the mouse settings in the Control Panel applet, but I didn’t fine anything unusual.

Does anybody know what could be the problem or how to fix it?

Comment: Does it work as expected in Safe Mode?  How about if you boot to a different OS (like with a Linux LiveCD, or your Windows 7 install disk)? Did you try a System Restore?

Comment: Try [Combofix](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/combofix/how-to-use-combofix)

Comment: sys restore didn't help. the problem occurred also in safe mode.

Comment: Have you tried each of the USB ports on the Latitude? Also be certain that your known-good mouse works in other machines. If it is a wireless mouse, are the batteries fresh?

Comment: Tried all the usb ports, and tried the usb-mouse on another machine - it worked. So the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

[System restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/system-restore) could be your friend.  Try rolling your system back to an earlier date to see if that fixes your mouse problem.

**Added:**  You might also try running the [System File Checker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**Added:**  Check to see if a [third-party shell extension](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/slowrightclick.htm) is causing the problem.  You can try disabling them using [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html).

Also, check whether the problem persists [in safe mode](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-hardware/mouse-buttons-not-working-with-windows-7/b79430c9-b7b7-4123-a51e-14dbae0ea993).  If it doesn't, then try performing a [clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135).

Comment: This didn't help, but thanks. Will be happy to hear of any other ideas.

Comment: @golan Okay, I've added a couple additional suggestions.

Comment: Shellexview did show me some programs i didn't know were running. Disabled some - didn't help. The problem occurs also in safe mode. Any other recommendations before formatting are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Check for wireless devices.

I had the same problem on two different computers at the same time
and they had both worked fine until . . . I powered on a wireless router.

Turned the wireless part of the router off and all returned to normal mousing :-)